# Cannot send messages using Messenger Send API even after mobile app asked for page_messages permission

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-send-api

In my mobile app facebook login I'm asking for page_messages and page_messaging_subscription permissions.

When I try to send a message to a test user from a Node.js server, I get this error:

> "(#100) Parameter error: You cannot send messages to this id"

The id is a app scoped user ID and the request is a POST request issued to this endpoint:

> https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=SOME_PAGE_TOKEN

Note: The user has not interacted with the page before.

Comment: Hi , have u got answer for this i m also looking for it